# iPhone App Store - how to determine the final size of the app when uploading

Tags: iphone, app-store

To clarify, I will be uploading new app to the App Store and I want to determine what the final size for the end user will be.
Currently, unzipped build file is 22MB and little over 18MB if I zip it (as per instructions for uploading new apps). My question therefore is which file size will be shown in the store? Do users download zipped archive or unzipped app file?

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roger's response doesn't take into account the additional DRM that Apple adds to your applications. This will generally add at least 1 MB to the final size, and this *does* affect whether or not it can be downloaded over 3G.

Answer (score 0):

That's not always completely correct. My zip was 19.9mb when I launched but the store read it as 20.1mb and thus it didn't qualify for anything but wifi downloading.

Try to stay away from pushing the 20mb limit...

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at My answer... The compressed size is wrong: [Did Apple change their app archiving method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371678/did-apple-change-their-app-archiving-method/5420505#5420505)